# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method :getUrl

Tags: magento2, error

i have an error which says Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method getUrl. The method getUrl is called in a block

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;
class BackButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Back'),
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href= '%s';", $this->getBackUrl()),
            'class' => 'back',
            'sort_order' => 10
        ];
    }

    public function getBackUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/');
    }
}
```

can someone help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code instead

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;
class BackButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    protected $url;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    )
    {
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Back'),
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href= '%s';", $this->getBackUrl()),
            'class' => 'back',
            'sort_order' => 10
        ];
    }

    public function getBackUrl()
    {
        return $this->url->getUrl('*/*/');
    }
}
```

You cannot use `$this->getUrl()` directly. Above code will fix your issue